# Highlighting text in bash when using reverse history search using Ctrl-R

Tags: bash, colors, search, readline

Using `Ctrl-R`, I can search the history in bash.

But what to do, If I want to highlight the relevant word which has been typed upon by me.

Example:

```
(reverse-i-search)`mount': sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

In the above reverse search, I want to highlight the world `mount` from the entire command `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`. How to achieve this in bash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readline` (which `bash` uses for its line editor) doesn't have that possibility.

`zsh` does it by default though. By default, it highlights the searched text with underlining, but you can change that. For instance with:

```
zle_highlight=(isearch:standout)
```

Or:

```
zle_highlight=(isearch:fg=red)
```

(`zle` is `zsh`'s line editor, like `readline` is `bash`'s).

Comment: For me, in `zsh`, does not seem to highlight anything for me. How do I check whether `zle` is really the editor I am using for this?

Comment: @Bernhard, possibly you have an old version of zsh. highlighting was added relatively recently circa 2008 (4.3.6 or 7)

Comment: Ah, that's clear. We are workin with the newest SLES here. `zsh` version is 4.3.6, so apparently added in 4.3.7. Thanks :)

Comment: With the release of bash 4.4, does this change: lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2016-09/msg00018.html ? See the feature mentioned in section 2 c for readline.

Answer (score 1):

So as of Bash 5.1 and Readline 8.1, you can actually do this.

From https://lwn.net/Articles/839212/:

> The most visible new feature is in Readline: the addition of `faces', which
> highlights the text between the point and mark (the region, so this is also
> called the 'active region'). This was added to show visibly the text
> inserted by bracketed paste, and also marks the text found by incremental
> and non-incremental history searches.  Faces are currently tied to
> bracketed paste and are enabled and disabled along with bracketed paste
> mode.  Bracketed paste mode is enabled by default.

[image: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/ka5xek/latest_readline_upgrade_causes_it_to_highlight]

*Picture source*: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/ka5xek/

Since it's enabled by default, you'd add the following to your inputrc to disable it:

```
set enable-bracketed-paste off
```